# Exclude specific url from loading interceptor in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I was using interceptor for loading spinner and it was great. However, i want to exclude specific http request url from showing spinner. Any possible idea how to achieve this problem?

controller

```
 $rootScope.$on('loading:progress', function (config){
      $scope.spinner=true;
  });

  $rootScope.$on('loading:finish', function (){
   $scope.spinner=false;
  });
```

factory/config

```
app.factory('httpInterceptor', ['$q', '$rootScope',
function ($q, $rootScope) {
    var loadingCount = 0;

    return {
        request: function (config) {
            if(++loadingCount === 1)

            $rootScope.$broadcast('loading:progress');
            return config || $q.when(config);

        },

        response: function (response) {
            if(--loadingCount === 0) $rootScope.$broadcast('loading:finish');
            return response || $q.when(response);
        },

        responseError: function (response) {
            if(--loadingCount === 0) $rootScope.$broadcast('loading:finish');
            return $q.reject(response);
        }
    };
}]).config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpInterceptor');}]);
```

Comment: please use the correct angular tag when tagging, dont tag angular if your question is angularjs

Comment: The url is a property of the `config` object. Check that to decide.

Comment: The statement `return config || $q.when(config);`  makes no sense as `config` always has a value.